# Disable vertical sync for glxgears

Tags: linux, 3d, glx

Sometimes you need to check whether you Linux 3D acceleration is really working (besides the `glxinfo` output). This can be quickly done by the `glxgears` tool. However, the FPS are often limited to the displays vertical refresh rate (i.e. 60 fps). So the tool becomes more or less useless since even a software render can produce 60FPS glxgears easily on modern CPUs.

I found it rather hard to get a quick and easy solution for this, I answer my own question. Hopefully it saves your time.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The `vblank_mode` environment variable does the trick. You should then get several hundreds FPS on modern hardware. And you are now able to compare the results with others.

```
$>   vblank_mode=0 glxgears
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was getting 59.984 FPS, which is the refresh rate. Setting `vblank_mode=0` I am now getting 1375.257 FPS on an old Intel i965  video driver running OpenBSD 5.6.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this only works for the Mesa open-source video drivers

Comment: Works for me using Radeon/Intel hybrid with Mesa

Comment: this kind of works but freezes the entire computer, requiring seperate TTY pkill on my machine (arch)

Comment: vblank_mode=2 is to enable vsync and vblank_mode=1 is to disable. vblank_mode=0 also works to disable as anything else but "2".

Answer (score 107):

If you're using the NVIDIA closed-source drivers you can vary the vertical sync mode on the fly using the [`__GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK` environment variable](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.43/README/openglenvvariables.html):

```
~$ __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=1 glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.631 FPS

~$ __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 glxgears
123259 frames in 5.0 seconds = 24651.678 FPS
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 14.04 using the 346.46 NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: It also works on Ubuntu 16.04, 387.26 NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: I seem to get similar results on all my machines. They're all a little above 20 thousand FPS. Is this a limit of Nvidia cards?

Comment: I got 47 thousand FPS on a GTX1050

Comment: It worked with 13k FPS for  a GTX 1050 Ti in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Also works on the Jetson Nano. I get about 2650 FPS.

Comment: Worked with 23k FPS on Debian (4.19 Linux Kernel) using nvidia-xrun with NVIDIA 1050 ti (Mobile) and 444.48.02 Nvidia drivers. I'm surprised with the 47k of our colleage drescherjm. I want to know how he did it. hahahhaha

Comment: In a pure doing the command "nvidia-xrun env __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 glxgears"  screen I got 24.5k FPS. I think it's not possible to get more. Well, glxgears is not a good performance test. hahahaha

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 23.10 with RTX 3050, using the proprietary driver version 525. `vblank_mode=0` did not work this time, but it did work in a different setup.

Answer (score 31):

### For Intel graphics and AMD/ATI opensource graphics drivers

Find the "Device" section of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` which contains one of the following directives:

- `Driver "intel"`
- `Driver "radeon"`
- `Driver "fglrx"`

And add the following line to that section:

```
Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       "false"
```

And run your application with `vblank_mode` environment variable set to `0`:

```
$ vblank_mode=0 glxgears
```

### For Nvidia graphics with the proprietary Nvidia driver

```
$ echo "0/SyncToVBlank=0" >> ~/.nvidia-settings-rc
```

The same change can be made in the `nvidia-settings` GUI by unchecking the option at `X Screen 0 / OpenGL Settings / Sync to VBlank`. Or, if you'd like to just test the setting without modifying your `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` file you can do something like:

```
$ nvidia-settings --load-config-only --assign="SyncToVBlank=0"  # disable vertical sync
$ glxgears  # test it out
$ nvidia-settings --load-config-only  # restore your original vertical sync setting
```

Comment: For Nvidia you can run `nvidia-settings --load-config-only --assign="SyncToVBlank=0"` to just change the X display's settings (and avoid modifying the config file or running the GUI).  After running `glxgears` you can run `nvidia-settings --load-config-only` to restore the config settings -- which you'll probably want to do since it's a persistent setting for the running X display (i.e. not just for the shell).

Answer (score 23):

Putting the other answers all together, here's a command line that will work:

```
env vblank_mode=0 __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 glxgears
```

This has the advantages of working for both Mesa and NVidia drivers, and not requiring any changes to configuration files.

Comment: Works in PopOS 22.04 LTS which is based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS !!!!

Comment: confirmed to work on Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 with a Quadro P2000 (according to nvidia-smi outputs) running with driver 4.70.233.02 and CUDA 11.4

Answer (score 7):

Disabling the Sync to VBlank checkbox in nvidia-settings (OpenGL Settings tab) does the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that works in the intel card and in the nvidia card using Bumblebee.

> >
>   export vblank_mode=0
>   glxgears
>   ...
>   optirun glxgears
>   ...
>   export vblank_mode=1

Answer (score 2):

For intel drivers, there is also [this method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Disable_Vertical_Synchronization_.28VSYNC.29)

> Disable Vertical Synchronization (VSYNC)
>
> The intel-driver uses Triple Buffering for vertical synchronization, this allows for full performance and avoids tearing. To turn vertical synchronization off (e.g. for benchmarking) use this .drirc in your home directory:

```
<device screen="0" driver="dri2">
    <application name="Default">
        <option name="vblank_mode" value="0"/>
    </application>
</device>
```

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Linking to some documentation is all well and good, but not enough to constitute an answer by itself (also links die, externally-hosted pages change etc.). Could you please summarise the key points in your answer?